# How to make the date appear 2 weeks later from current date inside a JOptionpane.showInputDialog

Tags: java, calendar, joptionpane

I'm trying to make the default value of an JOptionpane.showInputDialog to be the date 2 weeks from now. Everything i looked so far is to print on command prompt using System.out.println which i get it. But what should i do to appear properly inside my InputDialog. Right now it appears false.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,2);
fullname = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Please type the name of the client");
phone = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Please type the phone of the client");
date = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Please type the date of the Order",Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
ddate = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Please type the date of delivery",now);
```

Comment: Try adding 14 days to the Calendar instance.

Comment: How exactly am i going to do that?

Comment: Seriously?  now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 14);

Comment: Oh, i missunderstood you back there. I thought you meant something else. I found my answer though. all i had to do to appear properly was adding getTime() function to "now"